# mysql multiple NOT in where condition based on result from another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where in i need to pull data from one table but exclude some rows based on the rows in another table. I mean that i need to pull studentid(s) from one table but exclude those studentid(s) which are there in another table.

first query :

`$sql = "select studentid from table 2 where iarsid = '12'";`

as i'll get an array result from this query i want to use this result and put it in NOT conditions in the next query simply excluding these very rows from the result from this another query.

Second query:

`$sql2 = "select studentid from table 2, table 3 where iarsid = '12' // and a lot of joins";`

Basically the students who are in the first table are not needed while pulling out students based on the second query.
If i am using the wrong logic, please guide so as to achieve this.

Comment: You should avoid using numbers for table aliases

Comment: @Ray I think (hope) that's psuedocode

Comment: Also, no needed to quote integers in fact it will negatively affect performance of the query by making it cast a value needlessly if the corresponding column is of a numeric type.

Comment: do it with php.  it's faster and easier.  more lines of code though, but you'll probably spend the same time trying to figure out how to make the queries work.

Comment: yes @Raeki you are right i just used it for the explanation purposes only. Now if u guys have anything to suggest please do.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy i am using php and mysql only. if i am nt wrong, u are saying that i shall run a while loop looping the array from first query and append it to the NOT conditions in the second query. Please elaborate.

Comment: if someone can put up a sample code as an answer, i'l be really grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the general idea at least 3 ways, using a LEFT JOIN, and also using NOT IN and NOT EXISTS.

Via LEFT JOINS.

```
SELECT student_name
FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
WHERE b.student_id IS NULL
```

This gets all student information in table_A, where the student is not in table_B.

and here it is via NOT EXISTS:

```
 SELECT student_name
 FROM table_A a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT student_id FROM table_B b WHERE b.student_id = a.student_id)
```

and via NOT IN

```
 SELECT student_name
 FROM table_A a
 WHERE a.student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM table_B b)
```

Comment: Thanks but which one out of your three suggestions is faster and effective as i would need it to run on a lot of rows and a number of times in the day so i wudn't really want to hang up the database.

Comment: The NOT EXISTS version is slowest because it has to correlate rows from table_A to table_B for each row in table_A.  The other two options may perform differently depending on how things are set up.  If you have an index on student_id in table_A, and the number of results in table_B are not many, the NOT IN can be fastest, because you are comparing an indexed field in table_A to a not very large set of values coming from the subquery.

Comment: oh yes, the studentid in every table is indexed. if i index studentid in table_B too, will that help in improving the performance.

Comment: You probably should NOT IN and the LEFT JOIN approaches and time them for comparison. That's the definitive answer, because it's based on your data and design.

Comment: Alright, thanks a ton for ur help. this has been one of the many times that u have helped me, so thanks again.

Comment: It could help (indexes in both tables).  However, again if other criteria in your query against B limit the number of rows to a smallish set, NOT IN might perform best, because it's indexed in A and in B and you are needing to compare against a smallish set coming back from B.  Running it both ways really is the best way to see what works in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean second query that use the first query as a condition with NOT?

```
"select studentid from table 2, table 3 where iarsid = '12' // and a lot of joins"
+ " WHERE studentid NOT IN (select studentid from table 2 where iarsid = '12')"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i think this could work. Are u sure i dont need to loop through the array from the first query and append it to the second as not conditions.

Comment: sure, the 'IN' is the sql statement for this kind of usage

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have accepted an answer. But you can also do this. The best way to check which query is fast by checking your **`Explain` Plan.**

```
 SELECT student_name
 FROM table_A a
 WHERE a.student_id NOT EXISTS (SELECT student_id FROM table_B b)
```

Since this is an un-correalted query using `exists`, this will be fater for a larger table. And `IN` will be faster for a small table. The reason it's faster the moment it finds no match, it will return a false instead `IN` will do a full table scan.

Also this one:

```
 SELECT student_name
 FROM table_A a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null 
                   FROM table_B b
                   WHERE a.studentid = b.studentid);
```

Comment: @Nikhilverma you may give a shot on this too. Then compare your `Explain` plan :)

Comment: thanks man. i will certainly try all of the suggestions provided by all of you guys and will evaluate to use the most efficient one.